# Disable logs in logcat for every adapter invocation

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have built a hybrid app in MobileFirst 7.0 and I see in logcat that for every adapter invocation, there is a log with level 'D' and tag 'NONE' or 'WLNativeXHR' created, containing the server responses. I don't want these logs to be created.

I have tried to put

```
WL.Logger.config({'level': 'fatal'});
```

in wlInitOptions (initOptions.js file) but this behaviour doesn't seem to change.

How do I turn off client logging to Logcat (and the same for iOS) or at least change the logging level so that no adapter request/response is logged in the device?

Comment: What is your full version of MFP? 7.0-xxxxxxxxx, you can se this by going to eclipse > about > and choosing the mobile first icon

Comment: Version is 7.0.0.00

Answer (score 1):

It may help to upgrade your MobileFirst to the latest version. We have a few APARs out where we have changed the information that we were logging. We continue to log adapter invocation but we no longer log adapter responses.

For Android, another option is to look into using Progaurd. ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode.

Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended. (from Android Developer documentation: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

MobileFirst includes a progaurd project and all you need to do in that project file (progaurd-project.txt) is add:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
  public static *** d(...);
}
```

See Progaurd documentation on logging (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#logging)

In the project.properties make sure this is uncommeneted:
progaurd.config=progaurd-project.txt

iOS you should not see any logs in a production build. In MobileFirst iOS Framework code there is a macro variable set to check when the production flag is enabled. If the production flag is enabled then it will not print any MobileFirst logs.

Comment: So there is really no way to turn these logs off without upgrading mobileFirst? Isn't this a serious security issue? What if the requests and responses contain sensitive data?

Comment: I did add the code you told me in proguard-project.txt (and uncommented progaurd.config=progaurd-project.txt) but I still see the logs 

06-09 10:47:11.157: D/NONE(1990): {"your sensitive response data here"}